# Render data doesn't work in just one device

Tags: jquery-mobile, jsrender

At some point of my application I'm using jsrender to render some data into a listview like this:

```
alert("getData1");
var generatedHtml = $("#itemTemplate").render(data);
alert("getData2");
```

I'm testing the application in a desktop browser and some mobile devices (2 Galaxy Gio and onde Galaxy Note).

The problem is on one of the Galaxy Gio, because the second `alert` doesn't fire... All the others devices work just fine...

What could be the cause for this?

Comment: Do you have any kind of debugging information? Some kind of console error? It may be that you're trying to perform this operation before the html containing your `itemTemplate` has loaded - but some kind of error message will help immensely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem... It was a silly mistake...

I was importing the jsrender script with the location in the web, and for some reason, the device was not able to connect to the Internet.